# Python bmesh: Using selected edges on a curved object to create a face

Tags: python, edges, faces, bmesh

I am creating a parameterised model of a segmental tunnel-lining ring using Python and I have managed to create all the appropriate vertices and edges for the 'num_segs' number of segments in the ring. However, I have been having trouble creating the faces of the segments. I have written code that selects each combination of edges surrounding the 6 faces I want to create and then I run bpy.ops.mesh.edge_face_add(). But the results are not what I am looking for. The face that is created does not follow the curves and instead drops down on one side. I have tried with all edges selected in a clockwise and anti-clockwise manner and the issue persists. Here are my functions:

```
def create_faces(curve_res):
    # Object has been selected already
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    # Get the mesh data
    mesh = bpy.context.object.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
    
    all_edge_indices = generate_all_edge_indices(curve_res)

    for i in range(6):
        edge_indices_to_select = all_edge_indices[i]

        for edge_index in edge_indices_to_select:
            bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()
            bm.edges[edge_index].select_set(True)

        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)

        bpy.ops.mesh.edge_face_add()

        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)

        # Deselect edges
        for edge_index in edge_indices_to_select:
            bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()
            bm.edges[edge_index].select_set(False)

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
            
def generate_all_edge_indices(curve_res):

    all_edge_indices = []
    
    # To simplify
    indices_01 = [i for i in range(curve_res)]
    indices_23 = [curve_res + i for i in range(curve_res)]
    indices_45 = [2*curve_res + i for i in range(curve_res)]
    indices_67 = [3*curve_res + i for i in range(curve_res)]
    index_02 = [4*curve_res]
    index_13 = [4*curve_res + 1]
    index_46 = [4*curve_res + 2]
    index_57 = [4*curve_res + 3]
    index_04 = [4*curve_res + 4]
    index_15 = [4*curve_res + 5]
    index_26 = [4*curve_res + 6]
    index_37 = [4*curve_res + 7]
    
    # 6 faces on all the shapes
    for i in range(6):
        # Outer curve
        if i == 0:
            edge_indices_to_select = indices_01[::-1] + index_02 + indices_23 + index_13
            
        # Inner curve
        elif i == 1:
            edge_indices_to_select = indices_45 + index_57 + indices_67[::-1] + index_46
        
        # Front
        elif i == 2:
            edge_indices_to_select = indices_01 + index_15 + indices_45[::-1] + index_04
            
        # Back
        elif i == 3:
            edge_indices_to_select = indices_23[::-1] + index_26 + indices_67 + index_37
         
        # Left  
        elif i == 4:
            edge_indices_to_select = index_02 + index_04 + index_46 + index_26
        
        # Right
        else:
            edge_indices_to_select = index_13 + index_37 + index_57 + index_15
        
        all_edge_indices.append(edge_indices_to_select)
    
    return all_edge_indices
            
def angle_of_vector(vector):

    # Convert input vectors to NumPy arrays
    vector = np.array(vector)
    
    theta_radians = 0
    vector[1] = 0
            
    # Calculate the dot product
    dot_product = np.dot((0, 0, 1), vector)
    
    # Calculate the magnitudes
    magnitude1 = np.linalg.norm((0, 0, 1))
    magnitude2 = np.linalg.norm(vector)
    
    # Calculate the cosine of the angle
    cosine_theta = dot_product / (magnitude1 * magnitude2)
    
    # Calculate the angle in radians using arccosine
    theta_radians = np.arccos(cosine_theta) 
    
    if vector[0] < 0:
        theta_radians = 2 * np.pi - theta_radians

    return theta_radians

def add_circular_edge(bm, vertex_indices, radius, center_location):
    # Get the coordinates of the specified vertices
    vertex_vectors = [bm.verts[index].co for index in vertex_indices]
    vertex_coords = [(vertex_vector.x, vertex_vector.y, vertex_vector.z) for vertex_vector in vertex_vectors]

    # Calculate start angle
    start_angle = angle_of_vector(vertex_coords[0])
    end_angle = angle_of_vector(vertex_coords[1])
    
    if end_angle < start_angle:
        end_angle += 2 * np.pi
        
    angle_between = end_angle - start_angle
    
    num_steps = 16  # Adjust for smoothness
    
    angles = np.linspace(start_angle, start_angle + angle_between, num_steps + 1)
    # Add the curved edge vertices to the mesh
    for ang in angles:
        x = center_location[0] + radius * math.sin(ang)
        y = center_location[1]
        z = center_location[2] + radius * math.cos(ang)

        # Create a new vertex at the calculated position
        new_vert = bm.verts.new((x, y, z))
        
        bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
        
        # Connect the new vertex to the previous one (except for the first iteration)
        if ang > start_angle:
            bm.edges.new([bm.verts[-2], new_vert])

def add_straight_edge(bm, vertex_indices):
    bm.edges.new((bm.verts[vertex_indices[0]], bm.verts[vertex_indices[1]]))
```

For the images below I put a breakpoint above bpy.ops.mesh.edge_face_add() and then ran this function manually.

[image: correct edges selected]

[image: view1 of new face]

[image: view2 of new face]

Comment: You probably want to create multiple faces, not a single face. Your problem comes from the fact each n-gon (including quads) is rendered by being internally triangulated. This triangulation doesn't always go as you planned, and I even asked a [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/212459/60486) about that.

If you look let's say at a cylinder, it's not built from the top, bottom, and two n-gons on sides (1 n-gon wouldn't work for this [reason](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/210105/60486) ), it's just built from top, bottom, and many vertical quads.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to fix it by just selecting two opposing edges at a time and then running bpy.ops.mesh.edge_face_add() thereby creating many different faces to make up the curve. Thank you for your explanation :)